# Deserialise Object Not Known Until Runtime

Tags: c#, generics, deserialization

I've had a look round Stack Overflow and understand that what I planned to implement is not possible as generics are strongly typed at compile time.  However, hopefully, if I can explain my desired outcome, someone can point me down a different path.

I have a typename and some xml retrieved from a database.  For simplicity of this illustration they are below:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><Car xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">  <Name>Vauxhall</Name></Car>";
string classname = "Demo.Car";
```

What I ultimately want to do is have a car object so I can pass it to a form that displays Cars.  However, there are a small fixed number of objects that may be represented.

I know I could have something like the following, but have a vague hope that there is a more elegant solution:

```
switch(classname)
{
  case "Demo.Car":
    // deserialise into a car object and call method taking a car
    break;
  case "System.Collections.Generic.List<Demo.Car>":
    // deserialise into a list of car objects and call method taking a car
    break;
  case "Demo.Person":
    // deserialise into a car object and call method taking a car
    break;  
  //      and so on
}
```

Things I cannot control:

- Version of .Net (I'm on 4.0)
- What I receive from database

What I can control

- Everything else

I know people will ask why I want to do this.  Basically, we have messages flying around several topics on a message bus.  There is a component that captures received messages from a multitude of topics and saves the payload to the table I mentioned earlier.  These messages are not persistent (and nor can they be) and can be thought of as a broadcast to any listeners rather than a queue.  I have to retrieve the history of messages when the user interface is loaded.

### Edit 1:

For info, below is what I had hoped to do, but as explained at the top I know this is not possible:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(classname);
var myCarObj = Serializer.FromXmlString<t>(xml); 
// Serializer is a utility class we have. it only wraps the System.Xml.Serialization
```

Comment: How do you obtain `"Demo.Car"` in your example? Is it another field in the table? Then switch/case is the way to go, or perhaps `Dictionary<string, Type>`.

Comment: @Sinatr - yes, "Demo.Car" will be from a field in the table.

Comment: Look at [`Type.GetType(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx). Obviously you can't use generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionary to map `classname` to corresponding types:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, Type>
{
   { "Demo.Car", typeof(Car) },
   { "Demo.Person", typeof(Person) },
   ...
}

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(map[classname]);
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
   var result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help @Sinatr